# Use dataTables or filter and paginate in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, performance, pagination, datatables

I've like 6 or 7 controllers in which I've to show a list of elements in a table, that must be paginated and searchable.

I've seen a Javascript library called `dataTables` that allows to do both things (and column-based sorting) without dealing with code.

Is a best practice to do it in server-side (and unload the server from sending all the rows in the table) or use this plug-in (or something similar, that avoid send petitions to Rails for change page or do a search)?

Note that the number of elements in every table shouldn't exceed 100...

Comment: Not really able to give a helpful answer. But I will lead you to a useful suggestion: look up 'Angular.js'.. It's great for binding tables to data collections... You will have to study a bit though.. You will find many useful tutorials online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) throughout our app - it is very fast for searching, filtering, paging (nearly instantaneous) if you send all records to the client.

100 records is not very many, if you had 1000's/10000's then you would probably need server side processing.

If your database grows later, then you could still take advantage of DataTable's GUI and functionality by implementing datatables server side - see last part of [railscast #340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast) - The first part of that video is a great tutorial on how to get basic datatables up and running too.